# Separate the CSS styling from template in Angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is my angular directive for a template. I want to separate the css styling from template as when I use the custom tag in the html file like `<my-box></my-box>; <my-box></my-box>`, I can configure the css styling from a separate file for each tag. like `<my-box class= customStyle1></my-box> ; <my-box class= customStyle2></my-box>` where the `customeStyle1` and `customStyle2` are define in separate file as a Json style. like

```
{
 "myStyle":{
     "background-color":"#AAB000",
      "height":"100px",
       -----
       -----
   }
}
```

Here is my example [My Template](http://jsfiddle.net/laravinchi/FWPYJ/18/)

Code snippet

```
 counterbox.directive('myBox', function ($http) {

        return {
            restrict: 'EAC',
            template: '<div id=l1 style="height:100px"><table style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;border-style:solid black;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:2px" align="center"><colgroup><col style="width:33%"/><col style="width:33%;text-align:center"/><col style="width:33%"/></colgroup><tr style="color:black;font-family:sans-serif;font-size: 1em;font-weight:normal;padding-bottom:-5px;"><th style="text-align:center">X</th><th style="text-align:center">Y</th><th style="text-align:center">Z</th></tr><tr style=""><td style="background-color:lightblue;color:black">{{w.l}}</td><td style="background-color:orange;color:black">{{w.m}}</td><td style="background-color:red;color:black">{{w.h}}</td></tr><tr style="background-color:#BCC633;color:white;font-size:2em"><td id=g1 height="50%" colspan="3">{{w.s}}</td></tr></table></div>',

            replace: true,
            scope: {
                w:'='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                    
                scope.s = +scope.l + +scope.m + +scope.h;

            }
        };
    });
```

**## I actually used the templateUrl and separate possible common styling through external css file. There is two problems 1. this css file is not accessible to configure the user/client, they can only configure the Json file. and 2. if you notice in my table, each row has separate color. To modify those colors I need to use this css configure through the Json**

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a separate file for CSS (a .css file)
2. Use a separate file for your html template using the "templateUrl" instead of "template" in your directive (See [AngularJS Templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more information)
3. Include your css file in your .html template using the  tag (`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>`)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I don't want this way, I actually used the templateUrl and separate possible common styling. There is 2 problem 1. this css file is not accessible to configure the user/client, they can only configure the Json file. 2. if you notice in my table, each row has separate color. To separate that color I need to use this css configure through the Json.

Comment: @Altius How about writing javascript which would use jquery to dynamically execute the css from the json object using the jquery.css() method?